# why multiple input iterator will cause unexpected result?

Tags: c++, stl

Here is the sample code and the result compile using gcc4.8.1 in linux:

```
//content of test.txt
1 2 3 4 5 

int main()
{
    fstream fs ("test.txt", std::fstream::in );
    istream_iterator<string> is1(fs),eof1;
    istream_iterator<string> is2(fs),eof2;

    while(is1!=eof1){
        cout<<"is1:"<<*is1++<<endl;
    }
    while(is2!=eof2){
        cout<<"is2:"<<*is2++<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}


//result unexpected    
$./m 
is1:1
is1:3
is1:4
is1:5
is2:2
```

From the result, we can see when using multiple input iterator , it will give unexpected result. 
Could some one give me a hint why this would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered in 24.6.1/1:

> The class template istream_iterator is an input iterator (24.2.3) that
>   reads (using operator>>) successive elements from the input stream for
>   which it was constructed. After it is constructed, and every time ++
>   is used, the iterator reads and stores a value of T.

So when you create `is1` it reads `1`. When you create `is2` it reads `2` and then you iterate over the rest of the file with `is1`. Finally you print the single already-extracted value from `is2` and then end its iteration.